# Why does spring boot behave abnormally sometimes ? - Cannot find Autowired class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have been experimenting with spring boot since a while now, and I have noticed few strange things. Sometimes we have to include `@ComponentScan` in main class to solve the error which goes like `try defining the bean of type package.name` .
For eg. I created many sprint boot application without including `@ComponentScan` or any such annotation like `@EnableJpaRepositories` but recently I created one spring boot project which says `Cannot find bean of type RepositoryName` and when I used `@ComponentScan` , It worked. Why is that ?
You can see the code below:

Spring Class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.repository"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }


}
```

Entity Class:

```
package com.example.demo.entity;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity(name = "admin")
@Data
public class Admin {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "admin_id_seq" , strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="admin_id_seq",strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
}
```

Controller

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.dto.AdminRegisterDTO;
import com.example.demo.repository.AdminRepository;
import com.example.demo.service.AdminService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public AdminRegisterDTO registerAdmin(@RequestBody AdminRegisterDTO adminRegisterDTO){
        return adminService.registerAdmin(adminRegisterDTO);
    }
}
```

Service class

```
package com.example.demo.service.impl;

import com.example.demo.dto.AdminRegisterDTO;
import com.example.demo.entity.Admin;
import com.example.demo.repository.AdminRepository;
import com.example.demo.service.AdminService;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService {

    @Autowired
    private AdminRepository adminRepository;

    @Override
    public AdminRegisterDTO registerAdmin(AdminRegisterDTO adminRegisterDTO) {
        Admin admin = new Admin();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(adminRegisterDTO,admin);
        Admin savedAdmin = adminRepository.save(admin);
        AdminRegisterDTO adminRegisterDTO1 = new AdminRegisterDTO();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(savedAdmin,adminRegisterDTO1);
        return adminRegisterDTO1;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import com.example.demo.entity.Admin;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AdminRepository extends JpaRepository<Admin, Long> {
}
```

If I remove `@ComponentScan` I get the following error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field adminRepository in com.example.demo.service.impl.AdminServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.AdminRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.AdminRepository' in your configuration.
```

Comment: That seems odd. `@SpringBootApplication` encapsulates `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations with their default attributes. The default value for `@ComponentScan` means that all the sub packages on the package the `@ComponentScan` is used are scanned, so it should work without your own `@ComponentScan`. Is this all your code?

Comment: Adding `@ComponentScan` for a Spring Data JPA repository is useless as those aren't detected by regular component-scanning. (In fact the `@Repository` on the `AdminRepository` is useless it adds nothing). So I suspect that you changed something else as well (like adding some JPA configuration to your `application.properties` which fixed some JPA issue you had. Run the app with `--debug` to get get debug logging and the actual stacktrace of the underlying error instead of the analyzed one.

Comment: @JoãoDias Yes, that's my code. I know that's odd. But it's happening.

Comment: @M.Deinum, No I know what I did. In the same code with the same application.properties and maven dependencies, I removed ```@ComponentScan``` and it didn't work.

Comment: Well it shouldn't so there must be something else, deliberate or accidental that is causing this. So either this isn't your actual code (mismatch in packages for instance) at least I still think you aren't showing the actual whole picture but the picture you think it is. As stated run with `--debug` to get the underlying stacktrace and cause of the repository not being detected.

Comment: I am with @M.Deinum on this. There must be something else other than the code that you shared that is causing this behaviour.

Comment: What I suspect happens is that adding the component-scan actually hides the actual error by not instantiating parts of your application. So although it appears to be working I highly doubt that it is actually working.